# Value of differential equation at non existent points in the original function.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives

Lets say I have a function.
$$y^2+y=x^3$$...
Thus, the differential eqn will be..
$$y' = \frac{3x^2}{2y+1}$$

What does the differential equation give at the points that doesnt lie in the original function?

Comment: $y^2+y=x^3$ has 2 values of y for some x, so y is not a function of x.

Comment: @cineel In this case you have two branches for the "function". You can still find the derivative for each branch. Or if you want a single valued function, use $x$ as a function of $y$, and $y'=\frac1{dx/dy}$

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the equation $f(y)=g(x)$ leads to multiple branches, where if both $f(\cdot )$ and $g(\cdot )$ are differentiable, then a derivation of $y$ w.r.t. $x$ can be defined as $y'f'(y)=g'(x)$. The latter derivative makes sense as long as the points lie on the branches of $f(y)=g(x)$ and is insignificant elsewhere. Also note that for example in your case, $y$ can be defined as a function of $x$ on each branch ($y=-1/2+\sqrt{x^3+1/4}$ on one branch and $y=-1/2-\sqrt{x^3+1/4}$ on another), and whether or not this function can be explicitly found, $y$ in $y'=\frac{3x^2}{2y+1}$ should be replaced by some $h(x)$, for which $$y'=\frac{3x^2}{2h(x)+1}.$$